# How can I remove exponential terms and floating point numbers from a text file on linux?

Tags: linux, command-line

What regular expression should I use in order to remove exponential number terms and floating point numbers from a text file?

For example I have the following terms in my file:

```
-0.161678
relational
0.081827
5.936420e-01
-0.155506
Favori54
0.086938
1.187284e+00
-0.149283
0.091921
"External"
1.780926e+00
-0.143025
```

I would like my file only includes the following lines:

```
relational
Favori54
"External"
```

Comment: How about this example? http://regexr.com?36grk It can probably refined/optimised, since this one might be slightly crude, but it does work for the example you provided. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want lines that begin with anything *but* a digit or the minus sign. This will get you that:

```
grep '^[^0-9,-]' file.txt
```

Comment: Did you test this? It won't work. The regular expression will only match any first non-digit or non-minus sign. Also even if you add the `+` symbol to the end of that, it would still not match for `Favori54`

Comment: I did test it, with the lines listed in the OP, and it worked for me. `grep` prints any lines containing the pattern -- in this case, any line that has any non-digit-or-minus character as its first character. Since the tags specify linux, grep will be available.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but it's not as general as I need. The following one actually get all the things that I don't need. egrep -x '\-*''\+*''[[:digit:]]+''\.''[[:digit:]]+''\e''[[:punct:]]''[[:digit:]]+'  How can I just reverse this?\

Comment: Found the solution! I just needed to ad -v parameter. Here is most general version: egrep -vx '\-*''\+*''[[:digit:]]+''\.''[[:digit:]]+''\e''[[:punct:]]''[[:digit:]]+'

Comment: You should write that up as an answer (you can accept your own answer after two days IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^[+-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?$/ { next }
     /^[+-]?\.[0-9]+([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?$/ { next }
     { print }' yourfile
```

The mantissa part of the number, can begin with a dot, or end with a dot, but cannot just be a dot: `.` isn't valid, and adding an exponent like `.E3` doesn't make it valid. `0.` and `.0` are valid, with or without an exponent. The exponent may be an upper or lower case `e`, and may have an explicit `+` sign.

Note that this assumes no whitespace around the floating-point values. It also matches integer values. Furthermore, it passes through items which differ from the floating-point notation with junk characters or whatever, like `1E+`, `1.0A` or `.0E+33x`.  Note that some of these examples have a floating-point notation as a valid *prefix*.

The two regular expressions can be combined to avoid repetition of the common exponent part, and the common rule action. The result is even less readable, though.

Lastly, `{ print }` can be "code golfed" down to just `1`.  The expression `1` is Boolean true, and awk's default action for a true condition or matching pattern is `{ print }`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

> awk '{if($1+0!=$1) print $0}' filename.txt